# External CSS stylesheet link failure

Tags: html, css

I am having this issue here:

`http://arflux-rpg.com/game/index.php`

On line 5:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/src/style.css">
```

The stylesheet exists (and is populated in correct syntax), I am linking correctly, and yet the styles fail to apply.

**EDIT**:  Removed clickability of link as it's generating Google malware warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually mean to link to

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">`

Starting your url with `/` will treat it like an absolute path from your domain, without the slash it treats it as a relative path from the current directory.

Comment: You're fantastic. 11 minutes to go until I can accept this as an answer though.

Comment: Better answer than mine - I didn't check the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/src/style.css">`

with

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../src/style.css"/>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet may exist, but not under that path. Try to access it directly at http://arflux-rpg.com/style.css - you'll get a 404 Page Not Found error.

Check your path - you're specifying an absolute path with the leading /, so make sure the stylesheet is actually located in the "src" directory directly under your document root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the multiple chrome-extensions and thank me later.